# Duplicate rows when trying to grab last row of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to grab the last (latest) blog article's link for each month using a stored procedure but I cannot seem to find a way past my problem.

Currently, my code below repeats the (the latest blog article's) 'LINK' column like so:

[image: Results table]

```
SELECT AVG(DATEPART(mm, b.blog_date)) AS MonthNum --CANNOT USE MONTHNUM IN ORDER BY UNLESS WRAPPED WITH AVG() [average], weird but works
 , CAST(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, Datepart(MONTH, b.blog_date), -1)) AS varchar(24)) AS MONTH
 , CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, b.blog_date) AS varchar(4)) AS YEAR
 , CAST(count(b.blog_content) AS varchar(24)) as ARTICLES
 , (SELECT TOP (1) b.blog_url
     FROM Management.Blog
     WHERE (website_owner_id = 2)
     GROUP BY blog_date
            , blog_url
     ORDER BY blog_date DESC
  ) AS LINK
 , CAST(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, Datepart(MONTH, b.blog_date), -1)) AS varchar(24)) + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, b.blog_date) AS varchar(4)) AS ID
 , blog_date as DATE
FROM Management.Blog b 
WHERE b.website_owner_id = 2
GROUP BY CAST(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, Datepart(MONTH, b.blog_date), -1)) AS varchar(24))
  , CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, b.blog_date) AS varchar(4))
  , b.blog_url
  , blog_date
  , CAST(DateName(month, DateAdd(month, Datepart(MONTH, b.blog_date), -1)) AS varchar(24)) + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, b.blog_date) AS varchar(4))
 ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

I understand the code is horrible to read (& probably to execute on the SQL server too) but I'm in a position where I am only new to SQL server (coming from MySQL where I've only really had to use a basic select query) and I am open to any suggestions to changing the query and/or table design.

Essentially there should be no duplicates of the ID column (which is only really added in to assist in removing the duplicates and can be omitted if need be).

Comment: Can you please add your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data I'm unable to test whether this would work

After `FROM Management.Blog b`
Add this

```
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT   MonthNum   = DATEPART(MONTH, BL.blog_date))
            ,blog_date
            ,RN         = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY BL.blog_date DESC)
            ,BL.blog_url
    FROM    Management.Blog BL
) X ON  B.blog_date = X.blog_date
    AND X.RN = 1
```

Replace

```
(SELECT TOP (1) b.blog_url
     FROM Management.Blog
     WHERE (website_owner_id = 2)
     GROUP BY blog_date
            , blog_url
     ORDER BY blog_date DESC
  ) AS LINK
```

with

```
X.blog_url AS [LINK]
```

change this in `GROUP BY`

```
, b.blog_url
```

with

```
, x.blog_url
```

Answer (score 0):

I non-functioning query usually does not do a very good job of conveying what someone wants.  Based on  your explanation:

> I am trying to grab the last (latest) blog article's link for each month

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(b.blog_date), MONTH(b.blog_date), b.blog_url, b.website_owner_id
                                ORDER BY blog_date DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM Management.Blog b 
     ) b
WHERE b.website_owner_id = 2 AND
      seqnum = 1;
```